# Programmatically switch API naming conventions

Tags: java, c++, vim, naming-conventions, swig

### Background

The [FreeLing](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/) API defines an interface that does not adhere to standard Java naming conventions. For example:

```
package freeling;

public class sentence extends ListWord {
  public void set_parse_tree(parse_tree arg0) {
```

The interface is defined using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), which is similar to [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language):

```
class sentence : public std::list<word> {
 public:
  sentence(void);

  void set_parse_tree(const parse_tree &);
```

### Problem

Academically speaking, how would you map the interface to conventional Java naming standards (e.g., `class Sentence` and `setParseTree( parseTree arg0 )`)?

### Ideas

1. Convert the 650+ line [interface file](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=m4XPJ5sT) manually (and send a patch to the developers).
2. Regex [search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_variables_to_or_from_camel_case) voodoo (using vi): `:1,$s/_\([a-z]\)/\u\1/g`
3. Create wrapper classes from the 53 auto-generated Java source files.

Thank you!

Comment: Definitely (1), and send a *complaint* to the developers.

Comment: I would go with number 3, create a wrapper around it. If it has a naming convention you can even automate it if you think it will save you the hassle. Or copy the header and do a find/replace using regular expressions.

e.g
void set_parse_tree --> replace underscore + next letter with <nothing> + capital letter

Comment: Are we voting? I'm in for regex search and replace voodoo

Comment: @EJP: Why don't you send a complaint to Sun, for making Java naming conventions different from pre-existing style guidelines?

Comment: @Ben: Not to start a flame war, but various Pascal flavours, Smalltalk, Haskell, and likely others use camel/Pascal case notation. The purpose of this IDL file, though, is to expose a Java API, and thus should have followed Java's conventions.

Comment: Why does it matter? What is so terrible about calling a `set_parse_tree` function in Java?

Comment: @jalf: The question isn't about why it's terrible. Imagine, though, that your code had to pass naming convention policies before it can be checked-in. The question is about how to convert the API to follow standard Java naming conventions.

Comment: @BenVoigt If Sun's conventions offend you, why don't *you* do that? I personally don't care.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: I realize that, and that is why I posted a comment, not an answer. However, I would argue that such a check-in policy is *bloody stupid*, precisely because it's often impossible to ensure that third party code follows the naming conventions. And because it's so utterly superficial and insignificant, of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWIG provides a `%rename` directive that allows the names to be different in the client and implementation languages.  <strike>But doing this will nearly double the length of the interface file.</strike>

Actually, SWIG provides bulk renaming.  See [the documentation](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_advanced_renaming)

> 5.4.7.2 Advanced renaming support
>
> While writing %rename for specific declarations is simple enough, sometimes the same renaming rule needs to be applied to many, maybe all, identifiers in the SWIG input. For example, it may be necessary to apply some transformation to all the names in the target language to better follow its naming conventions, like adding a specific prefix to all wrapped functions. Doing it individually for each function is impractical so SWIG supports applying a renaming rule to all declarations if the name of the identifier to be renamed is not specified:
>
> ```
> %rename("myprefix_%s") ""; // print -> myprefix_print
> ```
>
> This also shows that the argument of %rename doesn't have to be a literal string but can be a printf()-like format string. In the simplest form, "%s" is replaced with the name of the original declaration, as shown above. However this is not always enough and SWIG provides extensions to the usual format string syntax to allow applying a (SWIG-defined) function to the argument. For example, to wrap all C functions do_something_long() as more Java-like doSomethingLong() you can use the "lowercamelcase" extended format specifier like this:
>
> ```
> %rename("%(lowercamelcase)s") ""; // foo_bar -> fooBar; FooBar -> fooBar
> ```
>
> Some functions can be parametrized, for example the "strip" one strips the provided prefix from its argument. The prefix is specified as part of the format string, following a colon after the function name:
>
> ```
> %rename("%(strip:[wx])s") ""; // wxHello -> Hello; FooBar -> FooBar
> ```

My recommendation is just to leave it as-is.  You're calling C++ functions, they have C++ names.  If anything, this helps you remember that you're calling out to C++ and need to follow C++ rules for object lifetime management, there's a slight JNI performance penalty, etc.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Your code will be exposed to the C++ abstraction.  C++ objects require deterministic destruction.  The Java garbage collector doesn't provide it.  Therefore your client code will have to manually call cleanup functions.  Waiting for the garbage collector to finalize a Java wrapper, letting the finalizer call the C++ destructor via JNI, that releases a shared resource, is a recipe for deadlock.  I don't know if that's a problem for this library, but C++ developers don't worry about their destructors being called late, so they don't design for that.

Comment: @Dave: Wow.  I can't believe you're consuming C++ code, with such a fundamental misunderstanding of RAII.  But maybe that's the downside of SWIG making wrappers easy.  I hope the library never opens files, or uses any other shared resource that needs to be released/closed on time.

Answer (score 1):

You know how you're not supposed to parse HTML with regex?  Yeah, don't write compiler-level logic out of regexes, either.  So not (2).

Don't rewrite their interface.  Their code expects it as well as other intermediate libraries you may use.  Not (1).

If you want to keep ugly code out of your code, write a wrapper-interface.  That way after sending a polite letter to them, or swapping out for a library made by developers who respect conventions more stritcly, you can migrate deftly.

Comment: Why would the developers deserve an angry letter, or be considered mentally unhinged, for following C++ code style in a C++ codebase?  The naming only appears non-standard when SWiG is used to allow other languages access to the C++ code.

Comment: Thank you. This is one of the ideas I have considered; but how would you automate the creation of the 53 wrapper classes? And how would you ensure that instantiation wouldn't leak their naming conventions?

Comment: Unless you have a background in compilers you can not automate writing a wrapper faster than you can write the wrappers manually.  Parsing syntax at this level is possible but not easy and unless you've studied the Java standards you're bound not to do it right.

But here's what I would do - write one by hand.  See what it looks like, find patterns, regex it up, then *review by hand* and make changes as necessary.  Throw out the messy regex code when done, it was a one-time aid, not a perfect production tool.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  incendiary language removed.

Comment: @djechlin: Much better, but you still claim they disrespect conventions, when I don't see that at all.  Why would you measure a C++ codebase by Java conventions?  The C++ conventions are being followed.  It might make more sense to say "swapping out for a Java-oriented library", or similar.

Comment: Because it's Java code.  Why not just change the .cpp to .java and let the client sort out the compile errors?  If it was autogenerated from C++ then that attests to the imperfection and dangers in auto-translating code from one language to another and *then* exposing the auto-translated code as a raw API.  Shouldn't Java-libraries be Java-oriented?  Perhaps not Java-orienting the library was a smart trade-off on the authors' parts, but there's no escaping that it was just that: a trade-off.

Comment: @djechlin: It's not Java code.  The only Java code is a wrapper using JNI.  The library is still in C++.

Comment: Didn't realize that, or that that technology existed within Java.  Good to know.  I'll leave my answer since I think it's still correct for possibly different reasons than I thought, i.e., I don't know how JNI mixes with "manually rewriting the interface" (but that sounds bad even without JNI.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same naming convention crisis when trying to integrate FreeLing JNI API and then I realized that this API was causing me hard time with the compilation cycle of my project plus performance wise was far from optimal (since it is internally recreating all the objects for every sentence you submit). I would recommend you switch to the analyzer server that comes in the bundle: [Client/Server mode Documentation](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/doc/userman/html/node84.html)

You can recreate what they have implemented in the PHP examples and the *analyzer.cc*.